# nginx invalid URL prefix with rewrite

Tags: nginx

I'm using docker and running nginx alongside varnish.

Because I'm running docker, I've set the resolver manually at the top of the nginx configuration (`resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=10s;`) so that changes to container IPs will be picked up without needing to restart nginx.

This is the relevant part of the config that's giving me trouble:

```
        location ~^/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ {
            set $args ''; #clear out the entire query string
            set $card_name $1;
            set $card_name $card_name_lowercase;
            rewrite ^ /cards?card=$card_name break;
            proxy_set_header x-cache-key card-type-$card_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                set $backend "http://varnish:80";
                proxy_pass $backend;
                proxy_intercept_errors on;
                proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
                proxy_send_timeout   86400s;
                proxy_read_timeout   86400s;
                proxy_buffer_size 128k;
                proxy_buffers 4 256k;
                proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
                access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
            error_page 503 /maintenance.html;
        }
```

When I visit a URL for this, e.g. `https://example.com/Test`, I get 500 internal server error.

In the nginx error log, I see the following:

`2022/04/27 23:59:45 [error] 53#53: *1 invalid URL prefix in "", client: 10.211.55.2, server: example.com, request: "GET /Test HTTP/2.0", host: "example.com"`

I'm not sure what's causing this issue -- `http://` is included in the backend, so it does have a proper prefix.

If I just use `proxy_pass http://varnish:80`, it works fine, but the backend needs to be a variable in order to force docker to use the resolver.

Comment: try to remove quotes - `set $backend http://varnish:80;`

Answer (score 0):

I've stumble across similar issue. I'm not sure why but defining the

set $backend "http://varnish:80";

outside of location block